# How to do mapping within powerBI when 2 tables have different header names for the same field?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table1 in an xlsx that has headers: a, b, c, d.
I have a table2 in a different xlsx that has headers: a, z, c, d.
(where "z" is a different name than "b" however is the same value). (i.e., just a different header name like "b" can be "sales" and "z" can be "revenue". They mean the same thing but are just different header texts).

Right now my PBI report has graphs that are created from **table1** xlsx import. (i.e., using fields a,b,c,d). For example: I have a bar graph that uses field "a" as x-axis and field "b" as y-axis columns.

How can I use query editor (or other feature) such that when I use **table2** instead, the graphs automatically update to use the fields from table2 even though they may be different names as table1 headers? For example: I originally have a bar graph that uses **table1** fields "a" as x-axis and field "b" as y-axis columns. But now since I have **table2** imported and not table1, I want my pbi report to automatically update the bar graph to use fields "a" as x-axis and field "z" as the y-axis value/column.

I was told there is a mapping feature to do this within PBI but idk how. I understand I can manually go to the graph and re-click what fields I want, but this PBI is pulling from a local copy of an xlsx that is going to be re-uploaded every week with new raw data, so the conversion of the headers need to happen within PBI if that makes sense. Otherwise if you upload the xlsx again every week it will just be the old headers.

I played around with the power query editor but am not experienced enough to figure it out. Not really sure what I'm doing. Unfortunately, online trainings in PBI don't really teach you advanced features like this.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery you can rename the columns by position

```
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(
    #"Previous step",
    {
        {Table.ColumnNames(#"Previous step"){0}, "New 1st column name"},
        {Table.ColumnNames(#"Previous step"){1}, "New 2nd column name"},
        {Table.ColumnNames(#"Previous step"){2}, "New 3rd column name"}
    }
)
```

Comment: I cannot do that becaues sometimes they won't be in the same position. For example lets say I have headers in order: a,b,c,d,e,f. Then I have another spreadsheet with headers a,c,f,e,d,b. Except they will be completely different names too.

Comment: If the columns in different tables are in different orders with different names, whats the methodology to know which column gets renamed to what?